# Unlimited storage with Chrome extensions chrome.storage.local?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-local) for Chrome extensions `chrome.storage.local` state:

> The maximum amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in local
> storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus
> every key's length. This value will be ignored if the extension has
> the **unlimitedStorage** permission.

However, the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/) for Chrome extensions permissions have a note alongside the `unlimitedStorage` permission which states:

> This permission **applies only to Web SQL Database and application
> cache** (see issue 58985).

It's unclear to me what this note means in regards to `chrome.storage.local`, especially considering the issue referenced is from 2010, which predates introduction of `chrome.storage` by 5 years.

Comment: Thanks but can you clarify- which docs are obsolete? The first or second? And are you saying that chrome.storage.local by default has no storage limit at all, and that the `unlimitedStorage` permission is useless? (Note that the second docs link is for manifest V3, which was released only a few months ago, so it would strange that it would include obsolete permissions.)

Comment: All docs contain a lot of obsolete info, it's updated extremely rarely. The new MV3 docs were simply auto-converted from MV2 and the conversion went bad so the current documentation is semi-broken. Also yes, unlimitedStorage is useless.

Comment: Wow ok, good to know - relatively new to extension programming so guess I'll have to presume a certain level of unreliability with the docs. Can I ask how you know the storage limitations have gone away- do you have other sources you can refer me to, or is it just based on your experience? (Also if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.) Thanks!

Comment: https://crbug.com/521077 is the closest thing to a proof, I guess. IIRC Chrome simply uses its global quota manager to allocate storage to extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm If it's not even in the official documentation, where can I find the exact specifications? Is the only way to check crbug.com out?