# What scenarios should unlimitedStorage be used in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, storage, adblock

This question was probably quoted earlier as well ([66454924](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354924/unlimited-storage-with-chrome-extensions-chrome-storage-local)) but my query didn't get resolved as per the comments.

So, as per the docs, unlimitedStorage permission have a note alongside which states:

> This permission applies only to Web SQL Database and application cache (see issue 58985).

but the storage permission says that the cap of 5MB will be removed if we use unlimitedStorage. The discrepancy is hard to understand. Also, where does IndexedDB stands in all of this? Is it covered by unlimitedStorage as well (I feel not)?

If the official chrome documentation isn't reliable, does there exist any other reference manual for it?

I tried looking into the chrome extension permission manual. I am observing adblock extensions and most of them seem to use unlimitedStorage permission. I am not able to figure out for which functionality do they actually need it?

Comment: The WebSQL note can be ignored, I think, apparently it's about the deprecated chrome apps platform. The only modern use for unlimitedStorage is removing the chrome.storage.local cap. As for IndexedDB, it is definitely using the standard quota manager that limits proportionally to the free disk space so it can grow to gigabytes.

Comment: I see. Both IndexedDB and localStorage use the levelDB storage style provided by google. Apart from the easy API understanding of localStorage, how does it have a noticeable performance advantage over IndexedDB? (Given `unlimitedStorage` removes the cap on the amount of data we can store)

Comment: Performance depends on the data, the way it is used, the place where it's used e.g. ManifestV3 service worker can't use localStorage.

Comment: Yeah true. But if I focus on the data fetching and storing part of the information flow and not the processing part, I cannot figure out much difference there. Sorry if I am missing something very obvious here.
P.S. I am analyzing memory storage in browser extensions and both `localStorage` and `IndexedDB` seem to store equally large key-value pairs.

Comment: The only way to assess performance is either to measure it directly and compare the results or to have specific parameters of possible data and the way it is used. One thing to note is that localStorage is synchronous and limited to 5MB so it has to be preloaded by the browser before the page that uses it is opened.